# Android json mapping retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, mapping, retrofit

I have problem with mapping json getting by request using Retrofit. I have dynamic 'data' object with similar nested object's.

```
{
  "data": {
    "DZ": {
      "country": "Algeria",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "AO": {
      "country": "Angola",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "BJ": {
      "country": "Benin",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "BW": {
      "country": "Botswana",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "BF": {
      "country": "Burkina Faso",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "BI": {
      "country": "Burundi",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "CV": {
      "country": "Cabo Verde",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "CM": {
      "country": "Cameroon",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "CF": {
      "country": "Central African Republic (the)",
      "region": "Africa"
    },
    "TD": {
      "country": "Chad",
      "region": "Africa"
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion how deal with it? I want to collect all object's in one list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everyone. I solved this problem using mapping. Also I used Moshi in order to convert json to kotlin model class, Retrofit for API call and Coroutines for easy asynchronous code

Below header data class which hold map of a country

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class MainModel(

    val data : Map<String, Country>

    )
```

Country class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Country(
    @Json(name = "country")
    val country : String,
    @Json(name = "region")
    val region : String

)
```

My api interface

```
interface Api {

    @GET("data/v1/countries?limit=251") suspend fun getAllCountries(): Response<MainModel>


    companion object {
        var api: Api? = null
        fun getInstance() : Api {
            if (api == null) {
                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.first.org/")
                    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                    .build()
                api = retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
            }
            return api!!
        }

    }
}
```

function in viewmodel class where I call api request

```
fun getAllCountries() {
       
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                
                val response = repository.getAllCountries()
                
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        //do your code
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        onError("Error : ${response.message()} ")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                onError(e.message!!)
            }


        }

    }
```

Here is useful links that help me understand Coroutines
https://medium.com/android-beginners/mvvm-with-kotlin-coroutines-and-retrofit-example-d3f5f3b09050

https://blog.mindorks.com/using-retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by making data classes in Kotlin as follows:

```
data class MajorData(
    val `data`: Data
)

data class Data(
    val AO: AO,
    val BF: BF,
    val BI: BI,
    val BJ: BJ,
    val BW: BW,
    val CF: CF,
    val CM: CM,
    val CV: CV,
    val DZ: DZ,
    val TD: TD
)
```

Now you will basically pass the response from the retrofit call to the `MajorData` class.

Now for better clarity, you should also make data classes for all objects such as `AO`,`DZ`, etc.

Example: (Taking `AO` into consideration)

```
data class AO(
    val country: String,
    val region: String
)
```

Please make the same for others as well.

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding! :)